# Anti-aliasing not working in Mathematica 10 and Linux

Tags: graphics, version-10, linux

#### This issue appears to be fixed in version 10.1

---

While this works fine in version 9, in version 10.0 the Antialiasing setting has no visible effect any more

> [image]

I'm here on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with Gnome 3.4.2 and an NVidia GeForce GTX 590 with NVidia driver.

Do others experience this and is there any known solution to the problem?

Comment: There is a visible change for me when I move the slider. Bodhi 2.4.0 x64, Radeon HD 3650.

Comment: Given the flashing problem you also reported: which graphics card driver version are you using, and is it the latest?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Currently updating to the latest. I wasn't thinking of this because in all other Mathematica versions and in the beta it worked.

Comment: Perhaps they linked against a different library version in the final build that introduced this problem. But this is sheer guesswork. If the problem persists despite the update I suppose you'll have to report it as a bug.

Comment: @OleksandrR. No, nothing changed with the latest driver. I have reported this to wolfram, but I always dislike sending them screencasts, images etc. Therefore, I regularly post the issue here and link in my bugreport to this site. Btw, do I have to mention that all the issues were introduced in the final release version of 10?

Comment: I have the same behavior (i.e. no visible change) under also under Linux with a NVidia card.

Comment: @sebhofer Would you consider upvoting the question then to indicate your interest in the issue?

Comment: Same issue on my end (nothing changes). I'm using internal Intel graphics (HD4000).

Comment: Same here with Xubuntu 15.04 and NVidia GeForce 7600 GS.

Comment: @shrx In 10.1 this is fixed for me.

Comment: @halirutan thanks, unfortunately we don't have a licence for 1.0.1 at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears fixed as of Mathematica 10.1.0, at least on my 32 bit Linux with NVidia Geforce GTX 750 Ti and binary driver 340.46, where the bug does reproduce with Mathematica 10.0.0.

Comment: Yep, seems to be fixed.

Comment: This is not fixed for me, in 10.1. I'm on a Mac with an NVIDIA GeForce 9400M and OS X 10.10.3.

Answer (score 6):

I had to modify the `/usr/local/bin/mathematica` script to fix 3D antialiasing.
It seems that the [`GLTest` script fails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99863/what-does-gltest-do-and-what-are-the-consequences-of-it-failing) and as a consequence Mathematica disables advanced 3D rendering.
The fix is to replace the line

```
GLTestResult=`${GLTest} 1 1 1 2 ${userDisplay}  2> /dev/null | grep "GLTest_OK"`
```

with

```
GLTestResult="GLTest_OK"
```

and now antialiasing works. Seems like a bug or improper test procedure to me. Tested with Mathematica 10.3.0 on Xubuntu 15.10 with Nvidia GeForce GT 730. Note that I did not have to `export MATHEMATICA_GL_FBO=1` to enable antialiasing.

Comment: I was wondering, do you have `libglu1-mesa` installed?

Comment: @ilian Yes: `libglu1-mesa: Installed: 9.0.0-2`

Comment: @shrx This is an awesome answer, because on my new machine, I swiched to XUbuntu and I have the same problem. Until now, I had no time to investigate further. It seems you did all the work for me :-) +1 of course

Comment: @ilian The missing dependency on XUbuntu 14.04 is `libMesaGL.so.1` for the `gltest` program. The library cannot be found although `libglu1-mesa` is installed. A quick google search gave me no real information why this library isn't there or whether it *should* be there. Does this help?

Comment: @shrx Would you mind to repost your answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101163/187). This is clearly a different bug and we should make an extra question for it. Please don't delete this answer until ilian has seen that we moved the topic.

Comment: @halirutan `libMesaGL.so.1` isn't missing, it's included with *Mathematica* and is on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime. The problem is not that `gltest` is missing a dependency, but that it runs and returns `GLTest_Fail` for some reason. This is being looked into.

Comment: @ilian Right. I saw now that this lib is given in the install-path of Mathematica and that `gltest` just fails. I have [updated the new question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101163/187). It would be nice if you report back and in case you need further information from my machine, just drop me a mail: `Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPChZhYGAoSCwpykzOdshIzMksKi1JzNNLSQUAgX0JmQ=="]`