# What does GLTest do and what are the consequences of it failing

Tags: linux

Antialiasing has never worked with 3D graphics in Mathematica on my linux machine. The solutions listed in the [related topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198/antialiasing-in-3d/) don't work in my case.
System specs: Mathematica 10.0.2.0, Xubuntu 15.10, Nvidia GeForce GT 730.

I went looking in the `/usr/local/bin/mathematica` executable script to see if there are some variables that control antialiasing.

I found this particular bit of code:

```
# Check for GL and GLU version
GLTest="env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${M_LIBRARY_PATH} SHLIB_PATH=${M_LIBRARY_PATH} LIBPATH=${M_LIBRARY_PATH} ${TopDirectory}/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/${SystemID}/gltest"
echo "$GLTest"
GLTestResult=`${GLTest} 1 1 1 2 ${userDisplay}  2> /dev/null | grep "GLTest_OK"`
```

In my case, the `GLTest` command translates to

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64 SHLIB_PATH=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64 LIBPATH=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64 /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/gltest 1 1 1 2
```

and the output is `GLTest_Fail`.

Why does the test fail and should I be bothered by it?

Comment: Trying `gltest --help` yields `gltest minGLMajor minGLMinor minGLUMajor minGLUMinor {-display DISPLAY_NAME}`. Not very informative.

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed as of Mathematica [10.4.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn104.html) (`gltest` is no longer being used).

Answer (score 1):

Compile this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("GLTest_OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And replace gltest with the compiled program.

It works for me.

Comment: In a pinch, `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\necho "GLTest_OK"' > gltest; chmod a+x gltest` will also do.