# Anti-aliasing not working in Mathematica 10.3 and XUbuntu

Tags: bugs, linux

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 on XUbuntu persisting through 10.3 or later**

---

I'm running a fresh install of XUbuntu 14.04.3 LTS with an NVidia GeForce GTX 970. I have installed NVidia driver 352.63 and OpenGL is working. Additionally, `libglu1-mesa` is installed.

Nevertheless, anti-aliasing is not working and cannot be adjust in the preference settings.

[The problem is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55340/anti-aliasing-not-working-in-mathematica-10-and-linux/101063?noredirect=1#comment274463_101063) that

> libMesaGL.so.1 isn't missing, it's included with Mathematica and is on LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime. The problem is not that gltest is missing a dependency, but that it runs and returns GLTest_Fail for some reason. This is being looked into. – ilian

Here is [a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99863/187).

Comment: This seems to be a very related issue of [of this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101063/187). Since the last issue was resolved with the update of Mathematica but this still persists, I'm opening this as new question.

Comment: See also [this issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99863/what-does-gltest-do-and-what-are-the-consequences-of-it-failing?lq=1)

Comment: I'm running dual GTX970s on Windows 10.  Antialiasing has no discernable effect.

Answer (score 5):

*Cross-posted from the [related issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101063/6849), this is the workaround that I found:*

I had to modify the `/usr/local/bin/mathematica` script to fix 3D antialiasing.
It seems that the [`GLTest` script fails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99863/what-does-gltest-do-and-what-are-the-consequences-of-it-failing) and as a consequence Mathematica disables advanced 3D rendering.
The fix is to replace the line

```
GLTestResult=`${GLTest} 1 1 1 2 ${userDisplay}  2> /dev/null | grep "GLTest_OK"`
```

with

```
GLTestResult="GLTest_OK"
```

and now antialiasing works. Seems like a bug or improper test procedure to me. Tested with Mathematica 10.3.0 on Xubuntu 15.10 with Nvidia GeForce GT 730 and `libglu1-mesa 9.0.0-2`. Note that I did not have to `export MATHEMATICA_GL_FBO=1` to enable antialiasing.

Comment: Works with Intel chip card. Fedora 23/Gnome. By any chance do you know if something like this can be used to fix antialiasing in other openGL programs, such as `glxgears` or Acrobat Reader for Linux (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300953/force-acrobat-to-render-asymptotes-figure-with-antialias?noredirect=1#comment734023_300953)

Comment: Would there be a similar fix for Windows users?