# Image3D does not give the distinctive blurry look, version 10 Linux

Tags: linux, image3d

The help file for [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html) shows two examples,

[image]

But when I try to execute this code on my system ("10.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 8, 2015)") I get the following

[image]

Is this a problem with my graphics card?  Is there a setting to change?

Even the "Neat Example" on the help page looks awful

[image]

Comment: Looks like an anti-aliasing issue, though I'm not sure how to turn it off or on in Image3D, which does not (obviously, anyway) accept the Antialiasing option.

Comment: 1. I get the same image on Linux (in VirtualBox) 2. This is not what it should look like and it's not what it looks like on OS X.  3. My guess is that it falls back to some approximation due to lack of driver/hardware support.

Comment: @bill-s I've noticed before that when I move the slider under `Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics` it has no effect at all

Comment: I don't think this is antialiasing-related.  Even within a single voxel, we should see a smooth gradient.  The shading should reflect the thickness of the opaque material we are looking through. [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HV4mP.png).  On Linux each voxel looks as if it were empty inside and only its faces ("walls") were semi-transparent.  Each voxel should look as if it were a solid semi-transparent volume.

Comment: I think [Mathematica fails to detect graphics capabilities on Linux](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101163/484) for some reason, [lack of 3D antialiasing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55340/484) being another symptom. For me the solution that worked consistently (both for invoking `mathematica` from the command line and for starting it from a launcher) was to [replace the `gltest` binary](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99863/484). I wonder if it'll fix your `Image3D` issues too (I haven't tried it out, but I see you also don't have anti-aliasing in your screenshots).

Comment: Just tested it, and yes, I get the blurry look on Linux with the `gltest` fix.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks so much! I will try installing the library tomorrow when I get back to my PC

Comment: @Rahul, I tried changing the gltest binary, so that now when I call `./gltest` from the binaries directory it returns "GLTest_OK" .  That didn't fix the problem, so then I changed the line in the `/usr/loca/bin/Mathematica` script to `GLTestResult="GLTest_OK"` as shrx suggested, and that still didn't fix it for me.   I tried to `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa` but I already have those libraries installed.  This isn't too big a deal, since I am not really making anything for publication with `Image3D`, I just noticed it wasn't working correctly.

Comment: FWIW I like the clean, sharp look of `Image3D` on Linux better than the blurry one.

Comment: @JasonB with my `GLTestResult="GLTest_OK"` hack, I get the blurred image regardless of `"InterpolateValues"` setting. Mathematica 10.3.1 on Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @shrx, I am confused by this, I tried the GLTest trick, I even downloaded and reinstalled the intel graphics drivers but no luck.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can do this using the `Method` option in `Image3D`.

```
Image3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 10, 10}], Method -> "InterpolateValues"]
```

makes the image crisp (as in the OP's version) while

```
Image3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 10, 10}], Method -> {"InterpolateValues" -> True}]
```

gives the anti-aliased (smoother) version.

Now I'm really confused... here it gives an error but turns the smoothing on/off anyway:

[image]

Comment: I can't really get that to change anything on my system,  http://i.imgur.com/jRoekld.png  - note just using `Method -> "InterpolateValues"` returns an error

Comment: Interesting abuse of `"InterpolateValues"` in the first instance.  Well actually it has nothing to do with `"InterpolateValues"` and only `Method`; try `Image3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 10, 10}], Method -> "foo"]` for example.  +1 nevertheless.

Comment: I think if you use the Method option with Raster3D you don't get an error. `r = RandomReal[1, {5, 10, 10, 4}];
Row@{Image3D@r, Graphics3D@Raster3D@r,
  Graphics3D@Raster3D[r, Method -> {"InterpolateValues" -> True}]
  }`. The first is default Raster3D style, the second interpolated Image3D style.