# Plotting a function with three real arguments using transparency

Tags: plotting, visualization

I would like to plot a real function with three real arguments by assigning a transparency and color to the function values. The smallest value in the plotting range should be fully transparent, the largest value should be intransparent and red.

The purpose is to quickly see the structure and the maxima in the plotting range, which should appear as red nebulous regions. For example,

```
f[x_,y_,z_]=1/(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)
```

is maximal at `{x=0,y=0,z=0}`. The plot command I try to build should produce a spherical nebula which is densest at the center. Ideally, one can adjust the transparency with a slider, or choose a log-scaling for the transparency, to increase the visibility of the maximum.

So far I did not find a method to do this in Mathematica.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Conclusions:

Below MMA 9.0 it is hard to do, from 9.0 onwards we have `Image3D` and `Raster3D` and from MMA 10 onwards we have additionally `DensityPlot3D` to do this. I have iterated *rhermans* solution to automatically scale and draw some coordinate indications (i guess the code golf people can put this in two lines or so...):

```
xmin = -3; xmax = 3; deltax = 0.2;
ymin = -5; ymax = 5; deltay = 0.2;
zmin = -7; zmax = 7; deltaz = 0.2;
f[x_, y_, z_] = z
tmp = Table[
   f[x, y, z], {x, xmin, xmax, deltax}, {y, ymin, ymax, deltay}, {z, 
    zmin, zmax, deltaz}];
min = Min[tmp];
max = Max[tmp];
m = -(1/(-max + min));
n = min/(-max + min);

xmaxint = Length[tmp]
ymaxint = Length[tmp[[1]]]
zmaxint = Length[tmp[[1, 1]]]

Graphics3D[{Raster3D[
   Table[{m tmp[[i, j, k]] + n, 0, 0, (m tmp[[i, j, k]] + n)^2}, {i, 
     1, xmaxint}, {j, 1, ymaxint}, {k, 1, zmaxint}]],
  Point[{0, 0, 0}],
  Text[{xmax, ymax, zmax}, {0, 0, 0}],
  Point[{zmaxint, ymaxint, xmaxint}],
  Text[{xmin, ymin, zmin}, {zmaxint, ymaxint, xmaxint}]
  }]
```

[image: Gradient plot of a 3-variant function with transparency, large values are more transparent.]

Comment: OK, thanks for the hints. I check in tomorrow. I tested your answer and it worked. I voted for your answer since it works also in MMA below version 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Image3D

Using [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html)

```
Image3D[
 Table[
  {f[x, y, z], 0, 0}
  , {x, -3, 3, 0.1}
  , {y, -3, 3, 0.1}
  , {z, -3, 3, 0.1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At a different range

```
Image3D[
 Table[
  {f[x, y, z], 0, 0}
  , {x, -10, 10, 1}
  , {y, -10, 10, 1}
  , {z, -10, 10, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

## Raster3D

Or using [`Raster3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster3D.html)

Here I'm squaring the Alpha channel for a more striking difference.

```
Graphics3D[{Raster3D[
   Table[
    {f[x, y, z], 0, 0, f[x, y, z]^2}
    , {x, -3, 3, 0.1}
    , {y, -3, 3, 0.1}
    , {z, -3, 3, 0.1}
    ]
   ]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm jealous that you can get `Image3D` to work.  I get crap [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I1s6C.png) when I try  :-(

Comment: @JasonB why do you get that? I'm using Mma 10.3.1 in Win 7 64 with *NVIDIA NVS 4200M* nothing fancy.

Comment: MMA is buggy in Linux is all I can say.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105909/9490

Comment: I can confirm that.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use [`DenistyPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html).  You can set your own custom [`OpacityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpacityFunction.html) and [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) (by default they take scaled values between 0 and 1)

```
DensityPlot3D[
 1/(1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 OpacityFunction -> Function[f, (Exp[4 f] - 1)/(E^4 - 1)],
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &)
 ]
```

[image: 3D density plot]

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be new in Mathematica 10. Thats why I couldn't find it.

Comment: I did look for something like this, but didn't find it. +1 !